# Why do I get an 401 error on /people/me/people/visible?

Tags: firebase, google-api, firebase-authentication

I use Firebase to sign in with Google. I sign in successfully.
I make a request to `people/me` using access token from sign in. Everything's ok.
I then make a request to people/me/people/visible using the same access token and I get an 401 (Invalid credentials).

Why is that? Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the request code please?

Answer (score 1):

Solved. I need to specify the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login` in order to have access to social features.